# 90s(?) cartoon series with two girls, one with pink hair

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Searching for the name of a cartoon. I remember there were two little girls in it, one with pink hair and the intro they were possibly sliding down a rainbow in space? And in a car at one point. They are in some sort of dream land?

In one episode the pony/horse they’re meant to be watching escapes and turns into a nightmare horse until they rescue him.

Comment: Futago Hime? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzLCnRY3txM

Comment: By the by, as long as you log in with the same account you can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

It’s [MoonDreamers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MoonDreamers), a spinoff of the My Little Pony franchise. I just searched for over an hour on everything I could remember and found it.

> The Moondreamers are a group of celestial people who create and
>   deliver pleasant dreams to Earth children. Their main enemy is the
>   evil Queen Scowlene who attempts to keep everyone awake at night with
>   her nightmare crystals.

Comment: Ah, can you explain why this matches for other people looking for it? Also, you will be able to accept your own answer 48 hours after asking (about a day and a half) by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

Could you be thinking of the *Rainbow Brite* cartoon? [Tickled Pink](https://rainbowbrite.fandom.com/wiki/Tickled_Pink) has pink hair, they do slide down rainbows, and Rainbow Brite does have a horse (as well as there being at least three other horses in the cartoon). I initially thought they had a car made out of clouds, but I think I was thinking of the [Care Bears Cloudmobile](https://carebears.fandom.com/wiki/Cloudmobile).

### Opening

Answer (score -1):

Strawberry shortcake also has a horse/pony.

https://m.imdb.com/title/tt10402962/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1

Comment: Can you expand on how this matches? Does Honey Pie ever turn into a nightmare horse? Is there a character with pink hair?